# How to memorize/store p:layoutUnit size on resize events

Tags: jsf, model-view-controller, layout, primefaces

I'd like to save in some variable (`menuSize`) the size of my `<p:panelMenu>` which is surrounded by an `<p:layoutUnit>` element. I tried the following :

**In my view (xhtml) :**

```
<p:layoutUnit id="myMenuLayout" position="west" size="#{loginBean.menuSize}" resizable="true" header="Menu">
  <p:panelMenu id="myPanelMenu" widgetVar="myMenu" model="#{menuModelGenerator.menuModel}" />
</p:layoutUnit>

<p:resizable for="myMenuLayout" onResize="#{loginBean.keepMenuSize(event)}" />
```

**In my controller :**

```
public void keepMenuSize(ResizeEvent event) {
  if (event != null) {
  menuSize = event.getWidth();
} else {
  logger.info("event is null !!");
}
```

But my `keepMenuSize` method is **not called** when I resize the menu, and the value of the `event` still `null` when I refresh the page into the browser

What am I missing ?

---

**EDIT :**

I've succeed now to make `keepMenuSize`method called using the following :

```
<p:layoutUnit id="boToolMenuLayout" position="west" size="#{loginBean.menuSize}" resizable="true" header="Menu">
    <p:panelMenu id="boToolPanelMenu" widgetVar="boToolMenu" model="#{menuModelGenerator.menuModel}" />
</p:layoutUnit>
<p:ajax event="resize" listener="#{loginBean.keepMenuSize}" global="false" />
```

But the problem now is that my method is called twice, for example :

When I resize my menu into the UI, the logger I've implemented into `keepMenuSize` method says that the size value is **475px**, then immediately after that says that the size value is **711px**.

Then if I resize again, it says **864px** then immediately **322px**...etc.

Does anyone knows why ?

Thank you

Comment: doesn't layout have its own resize ajax handler?

Comment: @Kukeltje yes, actually, I tried to user the `onResize` attribute of `p:layoutUnit ` but it still doesn't work

Comment: "still doesn't work" is not smart. It is an end-user description, not a developer one. Do some more debugging...

Comment: @Kukeltje "still doesn't work" mean that I already tried the solution you proposed before posting my question and my problem (aka the method is not called) persisted ! If you've read my question well you wouldn't have said that I'm not smart ! Thank you to contribute with constructive comments.

Comment: I'm not saying you are not smart;-) Sorry for the misunderstanding I meant it in the context of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMART_criteria. And 'method not called' is already 'smarter' but there are many related posts in StackOverflow about 'methods not being called' like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked

Comment: @Kukeltje Ok, but I already browsed stackoverflow for related questions/answers and none of them solved my issue. That's why I've decided to post a new question. this said, I've succeed to run the method using <p:ajax event="resize" listener="#{loginBean.keepMenuSize}"/>`` but something else is going wrong this time, because the method is now called twice. For example, if I resize my menu to 475px, it's first resized to 475px then to 711px automatically. I will edit my answer to include details...

Comment: See [ask] about the searching AND keeping track and mentioning in new questions...

Comment: Sure very logical (I think)... Try adding up both numbers... Notice something (1186?) ? The eventhandler is on the layout, not a layout unit. So it receives one event of something getting smaller AND one event of the other part getting bigger...

Comment: @Kukeltje, thank you for the remark. So, all what I have to do is to make the eventhandler only consider my layout unit, right ? maybe using `process` attribute ?

Comment: No, take the event in the eventhandler and from the event look up the component. You can then 'just' react on the relevant one...

Comment: @Kukeltje All I can do using my `event` object and to fit your suggestion is to test for its class : `if (event.getSource() instanceof LayoutUnit)`, but in my case I have the other LayoutUnit elements so this control is not relevant..

Comment: No... You can give the layout units an id and get that from the event and/or component to.

Comment: OK, I finally succeeded using the following code in my bean : `LayoutUnit layoutUnit = (LayoutUnit) event.getComponent();` then `if ("west".equals(layoutUnit.getPosition())) {`. Thank you @Kukeltje

Comment: And you can do `((LayoutUnit)event.getComponent()).getPosition()` (see [PrimeFaces Showcase source](https://github.com/primefaces/showcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/showcase/view/panel/LayoutView.java))

Comment: I'll write up an answer about this... or do you want to create a full nice one yourself?. Using the source helps... the PF source and the showcase source.

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes, both codes are approximately the same in my opinion :) For the answer, it's as you prefer ... If you write an answer exposing this solution, I'll validate it, otherwise I'll write my own, no problem :) Thank you very much for your time today